# Lambda - apply combination on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, lambda

Starting from the following dataframe:

[image]

I created the following function:

```
def campaign_name(name,ID,prefix):
    campaign = "S[" + prefix + ID + "]: " + name
    return campaign
```

I would like to use it in a dataframe like this:

```
keywords_merge_temporary["campaign name"] = keywords_merge_temporary.apply(lambda x: campaign_name(x.name,x.id,x.prefix), axis=1)
```

Problem being, for some reason I get the following error, which I never had in the past when I used this kind of lambda + apply combinations:

```
<ipython-input-...> in <module>()
----> 1 keywords_merge_temporary["campaign name"] = keywords_merge_temporary.apply(lambda z: campaign_name(z.name,z.id,z.prefix), axis=1)

/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)    4150  if reduce is None:    4151                         reduce = True
-> 4152                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)    4153             else:    4154                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
_apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)    4246             try:    4247                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4248                     results[i] = func(v)    4249                     keys.append(v.name)    4250             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-...> in <lambda>(z)
----> 1 keywords_merge_temporary["campaign name"] = keywords_merge_temporary.apply(lambda z: campaign_name(z.name,z.id,z.prefix), axis=1)

<ipython-input-52-f727ebf9b9ee> in campaign_name(name, ID, prefix)
      1 def campaign_name(name,ID,prefix):
----> 2     campaign = "S[" + prefix + ID + "]: " + name
      3     return campaign

TypeError: ("ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: Please post raw data and code that reproduces this, besides you can probably just do `keywords_merge_temporary["campaign name"] = 'S[' + keywords_merge_temporary['t1_prefix'] + keywords_merge_temporary['t1_id'] + ']: ' + keywords_merge_temporary['t1_name']` without using `apply` which is just a loop

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your dataframe? Looks like it's an issue of type (dtype). I wouldn't concatenate your strings that way, if you use the `'{}'.format()` methodology, you probably won't have that issue.

Comment: Added the dataframe I used. Anyway the version you suggested @EdChum works fine!

Comment: I think the problem is the `.name` attribute try this: `keywords_merge_temporary["campaign name"] = keywords_merge_temporary.apply(lambda x: campaign_name(x['name'],x['id'],x['prefix']), axis=1)` if so please stop accessing columns as attributes using dot notation and use `df['col_name']` style to avoid these errros